# Unable to disable frame button from JDialog

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jframe, jdialog

I want to disable a button on the frame from a JDialog, ***I tried everything but it won't work.*** The program's execution starts from a frame and when the button is clicked the Dialog pops up. Simple, when you click the button on the dialog the frame's button should get disabled and the dialog will close.

BTW: everything works, its just the frame's button that does not get disabled!
[image: Here's what it looks like]

PS: I am coding this on NetBeans so i have removed unnecessary coding for the sake of simplicity.

Here is the coding for the frame:

```
public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Dialog D = new Dialog(this, true);

public Frame(){
    setTitle("Frame");
    initComponents();
    setResizable(false);
}

void buttonDisable(){
    Btn1.setEnabled(false);
}

private void Btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    D.setVisible(true);
}                                    

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Frame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JButton Btn1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is the coding for the JDialog Box:

```
public class Dialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

public Dialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    setTitle("Dialog");
}                      

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new Frame().buttonDisable(); 
    dispose();
}                                        



public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't run this through an IDE. But I'm fairly confident that calling the buttonDisable() on a new Frame() instead of calling it on the actual parent frame is your problem.
You need to save your "parent" in your Dialog so you can access it later on and do something like this in your Dialog.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    parentFrame.buttonDisable(); 
    dispose();
}
```

So your complete code would look like this:

```
public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Dialog d = new Dialog(this, true);

public Frame(){
    setTitle("Frame");
    initComponents();
    setResizable(false);
}

void buttonDisable(){
    Btn1.setEnabled(false);
}

private void Btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    d.setVisible(true);
}                                    

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Frame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JButton Btn1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

and the dialog would look like this

```
public class Dialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

private Frame parentFrame;
public Dialog(Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    setTitle("Dialog");

    this.parentFrame=parent;//hold reference to the parent

    this.setVisible(true);
}                      

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.parentFrame.buttonDisable();//invoke method on the parent reference 
    dispose();
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, it doesn't work. What do u mean by saving the parent in the dialog?

Comment: @Anafam you are not calling buttonDisable on the right instance. Indeed you should keep a reference to the original frame and call buttonDisable on that frame (instead you create a new frame which is different from the first one). You should probably review the basic concepts of Java to fully understand your issue.

Comment: In your Frame code, you are creating a private variable Dialog (not really according to naming rules, but this is besides the point) which receives "this" as an argument. When we look at your Dialog code, we see this nice constructor which gets the Frame, and just uses the frame to call the super(). But what you actually want is to save that parent into a private variable so you can access it later, when you actually need it so you can trigger some specific functionality on that parent.
I'm also unclear on why you need a second main in your dialog

Comment: @3xil3 The Main in the Dialog was auto generated by NetBeans. I want the Frame to be the parent of the dialog i even tried making an object of the frame in the dialog's class `Frame frm = new Frame();` and then using that in the constructor `public Dialog(java.awt.Frame frm, boolean modal) {` and then setting in super `super(frm, modal);` but no luck!

Comment: @Guillaume Polet I'm not creating a new frame. I'm creating a Dialog that disables a frame button. I have no problem disabling the button from inside the frame But that's not my purpose!

Comment: @Anafam You actually are creating a new Frame in Dialog. Now that you have explained the purpose, I suggest you get rid of the entire main method of your Dialog. And to get back to your followup question. It's not the super(frm,modal) that's responsible for the functionality. What you need is a private variable Frame inside your Dialog, and in your constructor you assign the parent to that variable. So for instance this.parent=parent; would go in your dialog constructor. And then you can call this.parent.buttonDisable() in your actionPerformed of your Dialog.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it worked! But why do we have to set the parent variable as private? and why do we have to refer this variable to parent? is parent referring the Frame's variable to the dialog by any chance?

Comment: I'm used to encapsulate my variables. That's why I chose to make it a private variable of Dialog instead of a protected or public one.

We have to set a reference to the object inside the Dialog in order for us to have access to it after the construction of the Dialog has finished. If we don't hold a reference, we can't perform any actions on it later on.

The variable parentFrame holds a reference to the entire Frame object. This means that you have access to all public methods of that object inside your dialog object. This is the same reference as in the main.

Comment: @3xil3, I am not sure if it will work if the name of the `Frame` calling the `Dialog` is different. I think it should be **cast** to the class name of the calling frame. `this.parentFrame=(NAME_OF_FRAME_CLASS)parent;`
Here the two classes  have same name `java.awt.Frame` and the public class `Frame`